# Analytic functions and constants: Proving $f(z)-g(z)$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be analytic on some domain. Show that if $\Re(f(z)) = \Re(g(z))$ then $f(z)-g(z)$ is constant.

I haven't a clue on how to start. What is being asked of me & What am I looking to do?

Comment: I was editting that in just now, this isn't homework but practice questions for my final. Doing it for me provides no benefit.

Comment: HINT: Use Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: Hi, I have simplified $f(z)-g(z)$ to $i(v-t)$ where $v$ is Im(f) and $t$ is Im(g). Do I apply it here or should I do it directly on f and g (with an equal real part).

Answer (score 0):

If you write the difference $f(z)-g(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$, the condition that $\mathrm{Re}(f(z)) = \mathrm{Re}(g(z))$ implies that $u(z)=0$.

**Hint**: What does Cauchy-Riemann tells you, knowing that $f(z)-g(z)=iv(z)$ is holomorphic?

Comment: Partial $u$ With Respect To $x$ is equal to partial $v$ WRT $y$ are equaL but $u=0$ so both partial derivatives of $v$ are equal to $0$. Is this sufficient?

Comment: If the domain $\Omega$ is connected, then $\nabla v = 0$ implies that $v$ is constant in $\Omega$, which means that $f(z)-g(z)$ is constant. Do you know how to prove that fact?

Comment: No, I've never seen what you are doing just now before. I do know the C-R equations though.

Comment: It's a standard theorem in most multivariate calculus courses. Remember that the function $v$ is seen as $v:\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega$ is seen as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Fix a point $x_0\in\Omega$ and consider the set $S=\{x\in\Omega : v(x)=v(x_0)\}$. Since $v$ is continuous, the set $S$ is closed, and it's a consequence of the mean value theorem that it's open (prove it). Since $x_0\in S$, $S$ is not empty, open, and closed in $\Omega$, which is connected. That implies that $S=\Omega$ and thus $v$ is constant.